# Text box and Label issues

Tags: java, swing, textbox, label

I’ve started to create a GUI that consists of a few tabs.  Right now I am focusing on two of them.  The Pool tab and the Hot Tub tab.  When I first started I got everything to work fine on the pool tab.  So I figured since all of the label and text box placement would be the same for the Hot Tub tab I would just copy the coding over.  Well, I did that and tried naming all the labels and text boxes the same just with the number 2 after them.  It’s not working.  Now the Hot Tub tab works, but the Pool tab doesn’t, plus the text boxes are gone.  I’m also having alignment issues with the text boxes too, but I think that has to do with the naming of the labels and text boxes, I’m not sure.

MAIN CLASS:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;
private JPanel General;
private JPanel Pools;
private JPanel HotTub;

JTextField lengthText, widthText, depthText, volumeText;

public test(){
setTitle("Volume Calculator");
setSize(300, 200);

JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
getContentPane().add( topPanel );

createGeneral();
createPools();

jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
jtabbedPane.addTab("General", General);
jtabbedPane.addTab("Pool", Pools);
jtabbedPane.addTab("Hot Tub", HotTub);

topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
              }
public void createGeneral(){
General = new JPanel();
General.setLayout( null );

JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel("Today's Date");
dateLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 150, 20);
General.add( dateLabel );

JFormattedTextField date = new JFormattedTextField(
java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
date.setEditable(false);
date.setBounds(90,15,150,20);
General.add(date);

JButton Close = new JButton("Close");
Close.setBounds(20,50,80,20);
Close.addActionListener(this);
Close.setBackground(Color.white);
General.add(Close);
                         }

/*        CREATE POOL        */

public void createPools(){
    Pools = new JPanel();
    Pools.setLayout( null );
JLabel lengthLabel = new JLabel("Length of pool (ft):");
    lengthLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 260, 20);
    Pools.add( lengthLabel );
lengthText = new JTextField();
    lengthText.setBounds(260, 15, 150, 20);
    Pools.add( lengthText );
JLabel widthLabel = new JLabel("Width of pool (ft):");
    widthLabel.setBounds(10, 60, 260, 20);
    Pools.add( widthLabel );
widthText = new JTextField();
    widthText.setBounds(260, 60, 150, 20);
    Pools.add( widthText );
JLabel depthLabel = new JLabel("Average Depth of pool (ft):");
    depthLabel.setBounds( 10, 100, 260, 20 );
    Pools.add( depthLabel );
depthText = new JTextField();
    depthText.setBounds(260, 100, 150, 20);
    Pools.add( depthText );
JLabel volumeLabel = new JLabel("The pool's volume is:(ft ^3");
    volumeLabel.setBounds(10, 200, 260, 20);
    Pools.add( volumeLabel );
    volumeText = new JTextField();
    volumeText.setBounds(260, 200, 150, 20);
    volumeText.setEditable(false);
Pools.add(volumeText); 

JButton calcVolume = new JButton("Calculate Volume");
    calcVolume.setBounds(150,250,150,20);
    calcVolume.addActionListener(this);
    calcVolume.setBackground(Color.white);
    Pools.add(calcVolume);

JButton Close = new JButton("Close");
    Close.setBounds(350,250,80,20);
    Close.addActionListener(this);
    Close.setBackground(Color.white);
    Pools.add(Close);
                       }


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();
String buttonLabel = button.getText();
if ("Close".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){
Exit_pressed(); return;
    }
    if ("Calculate Volume".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){
        Calculate_Volume(); return;
    }
        if ("Calculate Volume".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){
            Calculate_Volume(); return;
    }
                                             }
private void Exit_pressed(){
System.exit(0);
                           }
private void Calculate_Volume(){
String lengthString, widthString, depthString;
    int length=0;
    int width=0;
    int depth=0;

lengthString = lengthText.getText();
widthString = widthText.getText();
depthString = depthText.getText();
if (lengthString.length() < 1 || widthString.length() < 1 || depthString.length() < 1 ){
    volumeText.setText("Enter All 3 Numbers"); return;
    }
        length = Integer.parseInt(lengthString);
        width = Integer.parseInt(widthString);
        depth = Integer.parseInt(depthString);
            if (length != 0 || width != 0 || depth != 0 ){
                volumeText.setText((length * width * depth) + "");
    } else{
        volumeText.setText("Enter All 3 Numbers"); return;
      }
                               }
public static void main(String[] args){
JFrame frame = new test();
frame.setSize(500, 350);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

HOT TUB CLASS:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public abstract class HotTub extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;
    private Component HotTub;

    {

    jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    jtabbedPane.addTab("Hot Tub", HotTub);
    JPanel HotTub;
    JTextField lengthText, widthText, depthText, volumeText;
    /*        CREATE HOT TUB        */


        HotTub = new JPanel();
        HotTub.setLayout( null );
    JLabel lengthLabel = new JLabel("Length of hot tub (ft):");
        lengthLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 260, 20);
        HotTub.add( lengthLabel );
    lengthText = new JTextField();
        lengthText.setBounds(260, 15, 150, 20);
        HotTub.add( lengthText );
    JLabel widthLabel = new JLabel("Width of hot tub (ft):");
        widthLabel.setBounds(10, 60, 260, 20);
        HotTub.add( widthLabel );
    widthText = new JTextField();
        widthText.setBounds(260, 60, 150, 20);
        HotTub.add( widthText );
    JLabel depthLabel = new JLabel("Average Depth of hot tub (ft):");
        depthLabel.setBounds( 10, 100, 260, 20 );
        HotTub.add( depthLabel );
    depthText = new JTextField();
        depthText.setBounds(260, 100, 150, 20);
        HotTub.add( depthText );
    JLabel volumeLabel = new JLabel("The hot tub's volume is:(ft ^3");
        volumeLabel.setBounds(10, 200, 260, 20);
        HotTub.add( volumeLabel );
        volumeText = new JTextField();
        volumeText.setBounds(260, 200, 150, 20);
        volumeText.setEditable(false);
    HotTub.add(volumeText); 

    JButton calcVolume = new JButton("Calculate Volume");
        calcVolume.setBounds(150,250,150,20);
        calcVolume.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        calcVolume.setBackground(Color.white);
        HotTub.add(calcVolume);

    JButton Close = new JButton("Close");
        Close.setBounds(350,250,80,20);
        Close.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        Close.setBackground(Color.white);
        HotTub.add(Close);
                           }
}
```

Right now both the Pool tab and the Hot Tub tab are the same.  No matter what tab I'm on, the same results show up on each tab.  Is it a naming issue?

Comment: There's a lot of code to wade through here

Comment: Could you please try to remove some of the code, and only include the relevant bits?

Comment: I removed some, and seperated the class, though I don't think it's right.  Please look at my original post.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in createHotTub() method:

replace HotTub.add( lengthText ); with HotTub.add( lengthText2 );

replace HotTub.add( widthText ); with HotTub.add( widthText2 );

replace HotTub.add( depthText ); with HotTub.add( depthText2 );

replace HotTub.add( volumeText ); with HotTub.add( volumeText2 );

Answer (score 2):

1. This should not be all in one class.
2. If your pool and hot tub tabs are so similar that you are copying code.  Instead create a new class that extends JPanel and sets up the panel based on some parameters.  (Or even just a factory method.)  Then add two of these classes to the JTabbedPane, one with parameters for a HotTub and the other for a Pool.
3. Use LayoutManagers.  It will be worth the learning curve and will greatly improve your GUI.